# Problema con horas y minutos

Tags: java

hola con todos tengo el siguiente código en java para capturar la hora y los minutos, el código funciona me devuelve la hora y los minutos del sistema pero, en horas y minutos menores a 10 me devuelve solo un dígito sin incluir el cero a la izquierda, por favor necesito ayuda para solucionar este detalle.
Por ejemplo me aparece 9:6, y yo desearía que aparezca 09:06.

```
Calendar Cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String fec = Cal.get(Cal.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + Cal.get(Cal.MINUTE);
    txtHoraSalida.setText(fec);
```

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta en stackoverflow en ingles, estoy seguro que es lo que buscas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599947/calendar-minute-giving-minutes-without-leading-zero

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) para lo que necesitas:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String hour = String.format("%02d",cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
String minute = String.format("%02d",cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
String fec = hour + ":" + minute;
txtHoraSalida.setText(fec);
```

*Nota:*  Prestar atención al nombre de las variables, no van capitalizadas.

*Nota 2:* `MINUTE` y `HOUR_OF_DAY` son estáticos, y deben ser accedidos como tal.

Ejemplo:

Si seteamos la hora de manera manual, podemos comprobar la salida correcta.

```
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 6);
```

Salida: `05:06`

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza este código para dar formato de dos dígitos.

```
 Calendar Cal = Calendar.getInstance();

 String time = String.format("%02d:%02d", Cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), Cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

 txtHoraSalida.setText(time);
```

Comment: Debería ser `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`, ya que son estáticos.

Comment: No lo había notado

Comment: Gracias por su colaboración, el código que me sugirieron me ha servido a la perfección...